# SQL count condition with 12months table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the following table Named: LISTON

```
| TYPE | MONTHS | New | Old |
+------+--------+-----+-----+
| A    | FEB    |  Y  |  N  |
| A    | MAY    |  Y  |  N  |
| A    | MAY    |  N  |  Y  |
| B    | MAY    |  Y  |  N  |
| A    | MAY    |  Y  |  N  |
| C    | MAY    |  Y  |  N  |
| D    | MAY    |  Y  |  N  |
```

I would like to arrange the data above into the format shown below:

```
| MONTHS |     A     |     B     |     C     |     D     |
|        | New | Old | New | Old | New | Old | New | Old |
+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| JAN    |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
| FEB    |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
| MAR    |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
| APR    |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
| MAY    |  2  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
```

Is it possible to do that in SQL? by count or by sorting? Or any other ways would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the details on what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
with
MyTable as 
  ( select 'A' as type, 'FEB' as months, 'Y' as new, 'N' as old from dual
    union all select 'A', 'MAY', 'Y', 'N' from dual
    union all select 'A', 'MAY', 'N', 'Y' from dual
    union all select 'B', 'MAY', 'Y', 'N' from dual
    union all select 'A', 'MAY', 'Y', 'N' from dual
    union all select 'C', 'MAY', 'Y', 'N' from dual
    union all select 'D', 'MAY', 'Y', 'N' from dual
  )
select *
  from MyTable
 pivot ( count(decode(new, 'Y', 1, null)) as new
       , count(decode(old, 'Y', 1, null)) as old
       for type in ('A' a, 'B' b, 'C' c, 'D' d)
       )
 Order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with `pivot`, e.g.

```
with pvt as(select * from mtable
        pivot (
          sum(case new when 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) new,
          sum(case old when 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) old
          for atype in ('A' a, 'B' b, 'C' c, 'D' d)
        )
        order by to_char(to_date(months, 'MON'), 'mm')),
  mnt as (select level mid, to_char(to_date(to_char(level,'09'),'mm'),'MON') months from dual connect by level <= 12)
select months, nvl(a_new,0) a_new, nvl(a_old,0) a_old, 
   nvl(b_new,0) b_new, nvl(b_old,0) b_old, 
   nvl(c_new,0) c_new, nvl(c_old,0) c_old, 
   nvl(d_new,0) d_new, nvl(d_old,0) d_old
from mnt
left outer join pvt using (months)
order by mnt.mid;
```

This gives output like:

```
MONTHS A_NEW A_OLD B_NEW B_OLD C_NEW C_OLD D_NEW D_OLD
------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
JAN    0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
FEB    0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
MAR    0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
APR    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
MAY    0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
JUN    0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
JUL    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
AUG    0     2     0     0     0     0     1     0
SEP    0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1  
OCT    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
NOV    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
DEC    1     0     0     2     0     1     0     1
```

Comment: What if the date is in the format of 17-MAY-2017? What should be user for Months in the above script?

Comment: if `months` is a date column you can use `to_char(months, 'MON')`, if it's a varchar2, you could do `to_char(to_date(months,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'MON')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using SUM CASE WHEN conditions as given below.

```
SELECT MONTHS,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.TYPE = 'A' AND A.NEW = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A_NEW,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.TYPE = 'A' AND A.OLD = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A_OLD,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.TYPE = 'B' AND A.NEW = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B_NEW,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.TYPE = 'B' AND A.OLD = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B_OLD,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.TYPE = 'C' AND A.NEW = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C_NEW,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.TYPE = 'C' AND A.OLD = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C_OLD,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.TYPE = 'D' AND A.NEW = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D_NEW,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.TYPE = 'D' AND A.OLD = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D_OLD  
FROM
MYTABLE A
GROUP BY MONTHS;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it by using `pivot` clause :

```
with tab as 
(
 select mon, type||new||old type from months m1 right outer join 
 ( select to_char(to_date(lpad(level,2,'0'),'MM'),'MON') mon, level mon_nr from dual 
   connect by level <= 5 ) m2 on ( m1.month = m2.mon ) -- you can replace 5 with 12 for whole year
)
select * from tab
pivot 
(
   count(1) for (type) in ('AYN' as "A (New)",'ANY' as "A (Old)",'BYN' as "B (New)",'BNY' as "B (Old)",'CYN' as "C (New)",'CNY' as "C (Old)",'DYN' as "D (New)",'DNY' as "D (Old)")
)
order by to_date(mon,'MM');
```

where the ***months*** table is created as below :

`create table months(Type varchar2(1),Month varchar2(3),New varchar2(1),Old varchar2(1));`

and the ***output*** is:

```
MON A (New) A (Old) B (New) B (Old) C (New) C (Old) D (New) D (Old)
JAN    0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
FEB    1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
MAR    0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
APR    0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
MAY    2       1       1       0       1       0       1       0
```

[D e m o](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f622f6/9)

Answer (score -2):

Since you tagged your post with *plsql*, I'm assuming you are using Oracle database.

From your description, it looks to me that you want to convert rows into columns. This can be done in Oracle using what's known as a *pivot*. This Web [page](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot) shows you how to write a pivot query. Hope it helps.

Good Luck,

Avi.

Comment: It would be better if you include the key parts of how to achieve this in your post, and link to the external page as a reference, rather than just providing a link.